# Is there an easy way to provide a custom django admin action without allowing changes to models?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a custom action on a model Foo all set up and ready to go, complete with a new permission I've made.

Problem is, my administrators need the can_change_foo permission to view a change list and perform that custom action (which I don't want to award).

Is there an easier way to set this up without rewriting the model list admin view?

Answer (score 0):

There is a **horrid** hack I can think of... Completely untested, obviously...

You could disable all other actions by overriding `get_actions()` and only allow for your custom action. Then you could [follow T.Stone's suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618728/disable-link-to-edit-object-in-djangos-admin-display-list-only) and completely disable links to edit individual instances of the model. What that would allow you to do is give your users the `can_change_foo` permission knowing that the only action they would be able to perform was yours.

Not pretty... Especially the part about not linking to the edit page...

Is re-writing the list admin view that bad? :-)

Comment: PS. Maybe it would be worth creating a ticket for a Django feature request in the lines of: "Custom admin actions that can be enabled based on custom permissions"?

Comment: Also - that suggestion to disable the links doesn't work for me in Firefox - the checkbox becomes "linked" and opens the edit object page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding the `changelist_view()` method on my ModelAdmin class, copying the defaults from django and just commenting out the permissions check. The list (at least the way I have it configured) doesn't have links to edit the individual objects, and even if it did, django raises a PermissionDenied if you try and edit an individual object. (since I never awarded the can_change permission).

It's a hack, and some monkeypatching, but until there's a separate permission for viewing a changelist, it works pretty well.