# Customizing each row of the model in admin page

Tags: python, django

I am customizing django admin template.

I can successfully remove button like (+add model) or some filter by changing overriding `change_list_results.html` and `change_list.html`

but now I want to customize each rows of the model to off the link.(I don't want to let the user go each rows editing page.)

I am checking `change_list_result.html`

```
{% load i18n static %}
{% if result_hidden_fields %}
<div class="hiddenfields">{# DIV for HTML validation #}
{% for item in result_hidden_fields %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if results %}
<div class="results">
<table id="result_list">
<thead>
<tr> 
{% for header in result_headers %}
<th scope="col" {{ header.class_attrib }}>
   {% if header.sortable %}
     {% if header.sort_priority > 0 %}
       <div class="sortoptions">
         <a class="sortremove" href="{{ header.url_remove }}" title="{% trans "Remove from sorting" %}"></a>
         {% if num_sorted_fields > 1 %}<span class="sortpriority" title="{% blocktrans with priority_number=header.sort_priority %}Sorting priority: {{ priority_number }}{% endblocktrans %}">{{ header.sort_priority }}</span>{% endif %}
         <a href="{{ header.url_toggle }}" class="toggle {% if header.ascending %}ascending{% else %}descending{% endif %}" title="{% trans "Toggle sorting" %}"></a>
       </div>
     {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
   <div class="text">{% if header.sortable %}<a href="{{ header.url_primary }}">{{ header.text|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}<span>{{ header.text|capfirst }}</span>{% endif %}</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</th>{% endfor %}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for result in results %}
{% if result.form and result.form.non_field_errors %}
    <tr><td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
{% endif %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

and found that `<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>` out the each row.

However how can I customize each `item` ???

Thanks for your any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django 1.7+, you can remove the links from the list from the admin model:

```
class UsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display_links = None
```

However, know that this will only remove the link - it will not prevent from users getting into the view/edit page of each row if they can come up with the relevant url. For that, you'll also need to handle that view as well.

See some of these discussions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837386/3121897

Comment: THank you !! it hits my spot!