# How can I hide (not disable) in Django admin the action add model button in ModelAdmin list view?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I am aware of the following questions which are pretty different:

- [Django Admin - Disable the 'Add' action for a specific model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143886/django-admin-disable-the-add-action-for-a-specific-model)
- [Disable link to edit object in django's admin (display list only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618728/disable-link-to-edit-object-in-djangos-admin-display-list-only/69461048#69461048)

My question is a little different: how can I disable the action button in the model list view, but retain the add functionality and links for all other Django parts (for example OneToOne relations and inlines). The code:

```
@admin.register(Document)
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name", "template", "file")
    fields = ["template", "name", "file"]

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

disables completely the add functionality of ModelAdmin (Django 3.2+, not tested in early versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is:

```
@admin.register(Document)
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name", "template", "file")
    fields = ["template", "name", "file"]

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return ("add" in request.path or "change" in request.path)
```

This will allow to maintain the "/admin/<app>/<model>/add/" functionality, also in popup.
The model list view will allow the model edit but it will not have the "add" button.